# Plotting ticks and custom grid lines at the same time

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to make a figure in Matlab that has grid lines at some custom places, but I also want to write ticks at regular intervals. Currently I produced the following graph, with the grid lines in the right position:

```
plot(myData);
xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Maginute');
set(gca, 'XTick', listOfTheoreticalValues);
set(gca,'XGrid', 'on');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', '');
```

[image]

The problem I am facing now, however, is that I can't put normal, equally spaced ticks on the x-axis, let alone with marking values, because that would immediately add extra grid lines too. Is there a way to separate the two things from each other?

Comment: Do you want the equally spaced ticks along the entire x-axis? One quick-and-dirty fix could be to overlay two plots (one blank but with the equally spaced ticks and one like what you showed in your question).

Comment: Or turn off gridlines, but leave the ticks, and then draw your gridlines manually - `for (v=MyPeaks),line([v v],ylim,'linestyle','--','color','black');end` is a template for that.

Comment: Or, inversely, draw the ticks manually using the above but with shorter lines.

Comment: The former option  (drawing the grid lines and letting Matlab do the usual ticks) seems very sensible, I like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hugh Nolan suggested, manually adding grid lines is one way to solve the problem. The following code will do the trick:

```
%Grid line locations
x_lines = listOfTheoreticalValues;
y_limits = [lower_y_limit; upper_y_limit]; %Insert desired y-limits here

y_grid = repmat(y_limits, 1, numel(x_lines));
x_grid = [x_lines; x_lines];

plot(x_grid, y_grid, ':', 'color', [1,1,1]/2); %First plot grid lines
hold on
plot(myData); %Then plot data to draw data on top of grid lines

xlabel('Frequency');
ylabel('Maginute');
```

Comment: This keeps the grid lines but removes the original tick marks, though.

Comment: How do you mean that it removes the tick marks? Perhaps naming the vector containing the x coordinates of the gridlines as `x_ticks` was misleading. However, no changing of any tick marks takes place. Will change the name of that vector.